# Unpack sympy lambdify function

Tags: python, sympy

Below code I have.

```
from sympy import * 
  
x = symbols('x')
expr = sin(x)
     
# Use sympy.lambdify() method
f = lambdify(x, expr, "math")
```

If `print(f)` its giving '`<function _lambdifygenerated at 0x100d643a0>`', is there any way to get back the expression(`sin(x)`) from f?

Comment: `help(f)` should display the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone into the source code of Sympy and found this line where the content of the lambdified function is defined in the variable `funcstr`:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/88b9cba9d7e633ec769baf1fc5267acfd7f54788/sympy/utilities/lambdify.py#L863

```py
# Create the function definition code and execute it
funcname = '_lambdifygenerated'
if _module_present('tensorflow', namespaces):
    funcprinter = _TensorflowEvaluatorPrinter(printer, dummify) # type: _EvaluatorPrinter
else:
    funcprinter = _EvaluatorPrinter(printer, dummify)

if cse == True:
    from sympy.simplify.cse_main import cse as _cse
    cses, _expr = _cse(expr, list=False)
elif callable(cse):
    cses, _expr = cse(expr)
else:
    cses, _expr = (), expr
funcstr = funcprinter.doprint(funcname, iterable_args, _expr, cses=cses)
```

Currently Sympy does not return `funcstr`, but I modified it in my local installation so that it does, and it seems to be what you are after.

```py
import sympy as sy 
  
x = sy.symbols('x')
expr = sy.sin(x)
     
# Use sympy.lambdify() method
f, funcstr = sy.lambdify(x, expr, "math") 

funcstr.split(":")[-1].split("return")[-1].strip()
>>> 'sin(x)'
```

The way I got the content out is a bit dodgy, and not necessarily robust, but I hope it gives you a starting point to work with.

Beware that if you used the argument `cse`, this extraction will not be accurate, since it will miss out on the previous simplifications.

Answer (score 3):

`help(f)` displays:

```
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x)
    
    Expression:
    
    sin(x)
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x):
        return sin(x)
```

`f.__doc__` is the same string.

Since we specified 'math', scalars work, but not arrays:

```
In [12]: f(1.23)
Out[12]: 0.9424888019316975

In [13]: f(np.arange(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <module>
----> 1 f(np.arange(3))

File <lambdifygenerated-2>:2, in _lambdifygenerated(x)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x):
----> 2     return sin(x)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: is there any way that I can expression in a variable? Basiaclly I need to dynamically create a variable which will include the expression from a _lambdifygenerated function

Comment: As far as I know the only record of that input expression in the function is in that `__doc__` string.